# Implementing third-party login authentication on my site

Tags: .net, authentication

I've noticed more and more sites allow you to login using one of your existing accounts with Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo!, etc., if you have one. (See http://jsdo.it/login for example.)

In other words, you visit foobaris.com and foobaris.com, and you don't have to create a new account specifically at foobaris.com—your login credentials for, say, Facebook, are authenticated from foobaris.com and your account user on foobaris.com is your Facebook account.

If I want to do this for a site of mine, am I going to have to visit Facebook, implement their proprietary authentication API, then visit Twitter, implement their proprietary authentication API, etc.—for each account provider?

Are there any open sources login frameworks that have abstracted these various APIs into a single API or component?

Answer (score 3):

There's [OpenID](http://openid.net/) and you may checkout the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) project which is an implementation for .NET.